# instalacion de bootstrap 4 en php

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

Anexado de Bootstrap

Estilos:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous"> //scrips que deberia ejecutar la apliacion->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

ERROR EN CONSOLA:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>               jquery-3.4.1.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>               util.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
>                   at util.js:55
>                   at bootstrap.min.js:6
>                   at bootstrap.min.js:6
>               jquery-3.4.1.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Segundo error:

> bootstrap-theme.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Me indica que no se encuentran dichas carpetas o el servidor no responde ¿qué solución me pueden dar?

Comment: Hola, no entiendo que relación tiene bootstrap con php, luego para resolver tu problema puedes obtener bootstrap de un cdn, a menos que tu sistema deba funcionar en una intranet sin acceso a internet.

Comment: Elimina el atributo *crossorigin* de tus etiquetas pertenecientes al mismo proyecto

Answer (score 0):

el navegador no encuentra los archivos en la ruta que pusiste. Si pones

```
css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
```

es una ruta relativa, significa que va a buscar el archivo en una subcarpeta `css` dentro de la carpeta donde esta el archivo html/php.

O pones ruta completa, o te aseguras que exista la carpeta correspondiente, o usas un CDN 
Ruta completa: `/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css`

Si usas el CDN, en [Bootstrap CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn) esta el codigo exacto a usar